# Sitecore webform for marketer module setup in CD and CM environment

Tags: sitecore

We have setup sitecore in such as way that we have one CM environment(this has access to core, web and master) and CD environment(this has access to web and core). We are using Webform for Marketer module in sitecore. Now on CD server, as we do not have master database entries in connectionstring.config and web.config file, when i try to use webform for markeret's module, it is failing while looking for master database.

The solution i have tried is adding `remoteWfmService` connection string in Connectionstring.config file.

```
<add name="remoteWfmService" connectionString="url=http://(Url for CM Server)/sitecore%20modules/shell/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers/Staging/WfmService.asmx;user=[domain\username];password=[password];timeout=60000" />
```

But this solution did not helped.

The error i am getting is **Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='master']** 
This is happening only on pages where i am using form created using WebForm for Marketer module. It is working on CM server as there i do have master database entries in ConnectionString and Web Configuration file.

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? Please post more details about your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're up-to-date with the Web Forms module version. The error you are facing with seems to be fixed in 2.2.0 rev.110303 - see the [release notes](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers%202,-d-,2/Release%20Notes.aspx) for details. If you're using Sitecore 6.5 (and thus, Web Forms 2.3), the fix should also be there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing the database with name "master". You should consider checking your connectionstrings.config file and see if the id's correspond and if the master exists. If it doesn't your should add the definition for the master database.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But this is happening on Content Delivery server. Now i have removed master database from web.config and connectionstring.config files as it is not needed on content delivery server.